# How to selectively rsync folders while retaining tree structure?

Tags: rsync

On my local machine I have a folder structure like this

```
/a/b
/a/c
/d/e
/d/f
```

I want to rsync `/a/c` and `/d/f` to a remote server so that after which it has folder structure like

```
/a/c
/d/f
```

Do I have to call rsync twice or is there an option can automatically retain the folder structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question. You need to use the `-R` or `--relative` flag. From the man page:

> -R, --relative Use  relative  paths.  This means that the full path names specified on the command line are sent to the server rather than
>   just the last parts of the filenames. This is particularly useful when
>   you want to send several different directories at the same time. For
>   example, if you used this command: rsync -av /foo/bar/baz.c
>   remote:/tmp/ ... this would create a file named baz.c in /tmp/ on the
>   remote machine. If instead you used rsync -avR /foo/bar/baz.c
>   remote:/tmp/ then  a  file  named  /tmp/foo/bar/baz.c would be created
>   on the remote machine, preserving its full path.  These extra path
>   elements are called “implied directories” (i.e. the “foo” and the
>   “foo/bar” directories in the above example).

Answer (score 1):

To preserve the directory structure, as above, use the -r or --recursive option (recurse into directories).

Then it is up to you how to make a seleciton. Use the -f, -F, --filter, --include or --exclude options.
If needed, you can also use --inclide-from-file or --exclude-from-file, specially if you end up with more than one or 2 filters/includes/excludes.